# Microsoft Graph only returning the "User.Read" scope with the password grant

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get emails from 365 salespeople emails of our organization.

I'm using `grant_type=password` and providing `scope='Mail.Read'`, but, no matter what I put on scope parameter, the API only returns `User.Read`.

I made the call like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{mytenantId}/oauth2/token
```

passing the following parameters:

```
client_id = myAppId,
client_secret = myAppPassword,
resource = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
username = vendedor@email.com.br,
password = passwordDoVendedor,
scope = 'user.read,mail.read,mail.send',
grant_type = 'password',
prompt = 'admin_consent'
```

it returns only `User.Read` no matter what I put on the scope parameter:

```
{#662
  +"token_type": "Bearer"
  +"scope": "User.Read"
  +"expires_in": "3599"
  +"ext_expires_in": "3599"
  +"expires_on": "1559623624"
  +"not_before": "1559619724"
  +"resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
  +"access_token": "...token..."
  +"refresh_token": "...token..."
}
```

Comment: I also use with spaces like this: "Mail.Read Mail.Send User.Read" (with spaces instead of ',')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify scopes with the v1 Endpoint, it is only supported with the v2 Endpoint (see [Scopes, not Resources](http://Scopes,%20not%20resources) in the documentation).

In order to add `Mail.Read`, you will need to add this to your application's registration in the Azure Portal.

I'd also be remiss if I didn't point out that using the Password grant is almost *always* a bad idea. It is fundamentally less secure than every other OAuth Grant.

Comment: I completely agree with you that using password grant increases risks, violates security best practices and is almost always a bad idea. Although I didn't follow the part where you mention `Note that the v2 Endpoint does not support the OAuth Password Grant`. I know you're an expert on both Microsoft Graph and Azure AD.. so it's possible that I'm missing something here.. but I am trying to clarify because I do see official documentation for v2 Endpoint supporting password grant here on Microsoft Docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

Comment: Interesting, it looks like it was added recently (albeit without MSA support). I'll update my answer.